How to deploy a website built with ktor for free?
I want to host the website that I build using kotlin with ktor. I'm gonna build a docker image and then will host it. But I am not be able to find a website that will deploy it for free. So it would be great if you suggest me a way (if that is simpler that the docker) and also a website but it should be free. Btw the website is a GitHub repository line counter.
I tried to host it directly without docker image using railway ig but it crashed.
